# set facebook comment using xpath and selenium

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium, xpath, comments

I'm trying to post comment automatically using my browser. for that I made this code

```
static void Facebook()
    {
        var url = "http://facebook.com";

        var email = "email";
        var password = "password";

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");


        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.Url = url;

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(email);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys(password + Keys.Enter);



        driver.Url = "https://www.facebook.com/CsharpCorner/photos/a.487296564614322.115393.194086953935286/1572378532772781/?type=3&theater";

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"/html[@id='facebook']/body[@class='hasLeftCol _2yq home composerExpanded _5vb_ fbx _-kb s_v05quun15 chrome webkit win x1 Locale_en_US']/div[@id='photos_snowlift']/div[@class='_n9']/div[@class='_n3']/div[@class='fbPhotoSnowliftContainer snowliftPayloadRoot uiContextualLayerParent']/div[@class='clearfix fbPhotoSnowliftPopup']/div[@class='rhc photoUfiContainer']/div[@id='fbPhotoSnowliftDetails']/form[@id='u_4b_5']/div[@id='fbPhotoSnowliftFeedbackInput']/ul[@id='u_jsonp_3_18']/div[@id='addComment_1572378532772781']/div[@class='UFIMentionsInputWrap UFIStickersEnabledInput clearfix']/div[2]/div[@class='UFIImageBlockContent _42ef _8u']/div[@class='UFICommentContainer']/div[@class='_fmi UFIInputContainer']/div[@class='_2xwx _289c']/div[@id='composer_text_input_box']/div[@class='_5yk2']/div[@class='_5rp7']/div[@class='_5rpb']/div[@class='notranslate _5rpu']/div/div/div[@class='_1mf _1mj']"))
            .SendKeys("123123");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.Quit();

    }
```

This workd perfect till `driver.findElement` I've copied that xpath using [xpath helper chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) but unfortunatelly I'm getting error that

> no such element: Unable to locate element:...

What can I do?

Comment: We need to use... dynamic xpath.... Can you give us DOM

Comment: @santhoshkumar I have url in question. see `driver.Url`

Comment: I have already logged in and hit the url. I am getting the enlarged view of the post and did we need to comment by clicking on the "comment" button in the right side?

Comment: All I want is to write comment in input on the right side http://prntscr.com/fghgmu

Comment: can you try this xpath. //ul[@class='UFIList']//*[@data-intl-translation='Write a comment...'] I am able to click the comment box using this xpath

Comment: I really have no idea why but I'm getting that error http://prntscr.com/fgj5ps

Comment: it can't even find `//*[@id='composer_text_input_box']` but it actually exists when i test using `xpath finder`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your XPath is too specific, here's what I would do:

First, when building an XPath, start by looking for an `id`, then look for "organizational" attributes like `class`, `name`, `value`, etc...

In your case, since you are using a tool to automatically generate an XPath, you should try to simplify it, looking for the same rules described above.

This would make it a little easier to debug, while making your XPath a bit more generic. This may solve cases where your tool is too specific when generating the XPath, for instance if an element's `class` is dynamically generated by some JavaScript.

---

Here's my process, using your XPath:

```
/html[@id='facebook']/body[@class='hasLeftCol _2yq home composerExpanded _5vb_ fbx _-kb s_v05quun15 chrome webkit win x1 Locale_en_US']/div[@id='photos_snowlift']/div[@class='_n9']/div[@class='_n3']/div[@class='fbPhotoSnowliftContainer snowliftPayloadRoot uiContextualLayerParent']/div[@class='clearfix fbPhotoSnowliftPopup']/div[@class='rhc photoUfiContainer']/div[@id='fbPhotoSnowliftDetails']/form[@id='u_4b_5']/div[@id='fbPhotoSnowliftFeedbackInput']/ul[@id='u_jsonp_3_18']/div[@id='addComment_1572378532772781']/div[@class='UFIMentionsInputWrap UFIStickersEnabledInput clearfix']/div[2]/div[@class='UFIImageBlockContent _42ef _8u']/div[@class='UFICommentContainer']/div[@class='_fmi UFIInputContainer']/div[@class='_2xwx _289c']/div[@id='composer_text_input_box']/div[@class='_5yk2']/div[@class='_5rp7']/div[@class='_5rpb']/div[@class='notranslate _5rpu']/div/div/div[@class='_1mf _1mj']
```

Start from right to left, looking for a node with an `id`, and removing all nodes to its left:

```
/div[@id='composer_text_input_box']/div[@class='_5yk2']/div[@class='_5rp7']/div[@class='_5rpb']/div[@class='notranslate _5rpu']/div/div/div[@class='_1mf _1mj']
```

Start from right to left again, looking for a node with an attribute, and removing all nodes to its left, except for the `id` node:

```
/div[@id='composer_text_input_box']/div[@class='_1mf _1mj']
```

Add a `/` before both the `id` node and the attribute node. `//` signifies matching nodes recursively down the DOM tree.

```
//div[@id='composer_text_input_box']//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']
```

Finally, verify correctness in the browser's console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) by searching (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for the XPath.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to successfully add comment on Facebook using Selenium .

**Here is the Java code:**

```
    String url = "http://facebook.com";

    String email = "email";
    String password = "password";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/chromedriver 3");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");


    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get(url);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Your email ID");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Your password" + Keys.ENTER);
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/CsharpCorner/photos/a.487296564614322.115393.194086953935286/1572378532772781/?type=3&theater");



    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement element_comment= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='UFIList']/div[contains(@id,'addComment')]//div[@class='UFICommentContainer']//div[contains(@class,'UFIAddCommentInput')]"));

    element_comment.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@contenteditable='true']")).sendKeys("Hello World");
```

Note:

- The path which you have used for clicking the element cannot be used for sending keys on the element and vice versa.
- There is a div with attribute **contenteditable ="true".**  You will be able to see this div in the HTML after clicking on the comment box.